# Rendering static PDF from reactJS using react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, pdf

Here is my code. Webpack loads the PDF alright. The react component does not render the pdf. When accessing through the react component it brings a blank page with page no. 1 of 
When put the following url in the browser it renders the pdf from browser directly and is alright.

http://localhost:3000/bfa955d1b47a762fb2b4d8cc2525f637.pdf

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import myPdf from '../images/BSOAANZChapterConstitution.pdf'
import {Document, Page} from 'react-pdf/build/entry.webpack';

class Constitution extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            numPages: null,
            pageNumber: 1
        };
    }

    onDocumentLoad({numPages}) {
        this.setState({numPages});
    }

    render() {

        const {pageNumber, numPages} = this.setState;
        return (
            <div>
                <Document
                    file={myPdf} onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoad}>
                    <Page pageNumber={pageNumber}/>
                </Document>
                <p>Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Constitution;
```

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is just because of not binding `this.onDocumentLoad` event handler to `this`. If you want to access properties, state and component methods like setState from event handlers, you need to bind that handler to `this`. So, within the constructor add the following.

`this.onDocumentLoad = this.onDocumentLoad.bind(this)`

Answer (score 0):

I added the line mentioned in the above suggestion. It dint work. I tried a few other packages too, they din't work. It was the same problem, no errors but pdf was not being loaded.
I got it working now by using react-pdf-js-infinite, I am not sure if it also allows navigation controls and page numbers. But so far, it at least renders the pdf.

[react-pdf-infinite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-js-infinite)
 Code was just one import and file specification.

```
class Constitution extends Component {
   render() {
        return (
            <PDF file={myPdf} scale={1.5} />
        );
    }
}

export default Constitution;
```